# How to properly call elements in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote a script that reads in several .txt files and fills in a 2D np array named y. y has 12 rows and 4 columns. Below are the printouts for y, and several row and column ranges. How am I getting the same row for `y[0:12][0]` and `y1[0][0:12]`? I am completely lost as to what is happening here. I got my code to work a different way, without using a 2D array, but I can't live peacefully without understanding what I am doing wrong here. I feel like its a silly mistake.

```
print(y)
[['0.7202', '0.3344', '0.4673', '1.480'], 
['0.6879', '0.3133', '0.4359', '1.358'], 
['0.5888', '0.2536', '0.3494', '1.018'], 
['0.4579', '0.182', '0.2482', '0.6607'], 
['0.7271', '0.5603', '0.7601', '1.832'], 
['0.8885', '1.106', '1.441', '2.628'], 
['1.251', '2.111', '2.552', '3.695'], 
['1.842', '3.712', '4.153', '5.135'], 
['1.415', '1.768', '2.602', '7.858'], 
['2.892', '5.557', '7.303', '15.74'], 
['5.635', '13.94', '16.00', '26.41'], 
['9.860', '27.31', '27.72', '36.66']]

print(y[0:12][0])
['0.7202', '0.3344', '0.4673', '1.480']

print(y1[0][0:12])
['0.7202', '0.3344', '0.4673', '1.480']
```

I expected the code to give the values of the first column, so `y[0:12][0] = (0.7202,.....,9.860)`.

Comment: You don't use multiple indexes like nested lists. Use `y[0:12,0]`

Comment: I was actually using a 2D list, and not an np.array. Sorry for the confusion there. Not sure why my method didn't work, but switching it to an np.array fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I thought something was wrong, since printing a numpy array doesn't put commas between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use comma-separated indexes.

```
>>> y = np.array([['0.7202', '0.3344', '0.4673', '1.480'], 
... ['0.6879', '0.3133', '0.4359', '1.358'], 
... ['0.5888', '0.2536', '0.3494', '1.018'], 
... ['0.4579', '0.182', '0.2482', '0.6607'], 
... ['0.7271', '0.5603', '0.7601', '1.832'], 
... ['0.8885', '1.106', '1.441', '2.628'], 
... ['1.251', '2.111', '2.552', '3.695'], 
... ['1.842', '3.712', '4.153', '5.135'], 
... ['1.415', '1.768', '2.602', '7.858'], 
... ['2.892', '5.557', '7.303', '15.74'], 
... ['5.635', '13.94', '16.00', '26.41'], 
... ['9.860', '27.31', '27.72', '36.66']])
>>> print(y[:, 0]) # first column
['0.7202' '0.6879' '0.5888' '0.4579' '0.7271' '0.8885' '1.251' '1.842'
 '1.415' '2.892' '5.635' '9.860']
>>> print(y[0, :]) # first row
['0.7202' '0.3344' '0.4673' '1.480']
```

Comment: My mistake, I was actually filling in a list and not an np.array. Which still has me confused as to why my initial method didn't work, but can live with your solution. Thanks.

Comment: `y[0:12]` is just a copy of `y`, so `y[0:12][0]` is the same as `y[0]`. `y[0]` is the first element of `y`, so `y[0][0:12]` is a slice of `y[0]`, which is a copy of `y[0]`.